# Yii: Different format In DB and In HTML Input field?

Tags: yii

I have a MySQL database with date field in format like "2013-04-05".

I also have CActiveForm with a text input which accepts values like "05/10/2013".

What is the proper way to convert between these formats when loading and when submitting the form? Which method do I need to override?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common problem, a lot of solutions, here is a simple one :

Use a virtual attribute, e.g. in your model :

```
public $dateIncomeFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
public $dateOutcomeFormat = 'dd/MM/yyyy';

// get date (FR means french)
public function getDateFR()
{
    return Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format($this->dateOutcomeFormat, CDateTimeParser::parse($this->date, $this->dateIncomeFormat));
}

// set dateFR
public function setDateFR($date)
{
    $this->date = Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format($this->dateIncomeFormat, CDateTimeParser::parse($date, $this->dateOutcomeFormat));
}
```

You should then :

- declare `dateFR` in your model's rules,
- and use `dateFR` in your forms instead of `date`.

You should also read this :

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n#date-and-time-formatting
- http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/i18n-datetime-behavior/

Answer (score 0):

if date `2013-04-05` has format *yyyy-mm-dd* and `05/10/2013` has format *dd-mm-yyyy* you can use:

`2013-04-05` => `05/10/2013`

```
$date = implode('/', array_reverse(explode('-', '2013-04-05')));
```

`05/10/2013` => `2013-04-05`

```
$date = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', '05/10/2013')));
```

If you have other date format - here is more flexible functions

```
// if $date = '05/10/2013' (mm-dd-yyyy) e.g.
function dateToMysql($date, $format = 'd-m-Y') {
    $date = explode('/',$date);
    return date($format, strtotime($date[1]."-".$date[0]."-".$date[2]));
}

// if $date = '2013-04-05' (yyyy-mm-dd) e.g.
function mysqlToDate($date, $format = 'm/d/Y') {
    $date = explode('-',$date);
    return date($format, strtotime($date[0]."-".$date[1]."-".$date[2]));
}
```

Comment: I've asked in which method to do the conversion, not how to use explode() (what I already know)

Comment: why do not use it in controller method where you validate your form or in model beforeSave()?